# Pseudo class first-of-type affect all buttons

Tags: css

For some strange reason the pseudo class first-of-type don't work! All buttons are affected. I just want the first to be affected. What could be wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="selectedBuildingButtons">  
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>1</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selectedBuildingButtons a 
{
display: block;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
background: #c3c3c3;
padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #fff;
}

.selectedBuildingButtons a:first-of-type
{
background: #2d2d2d !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks for first-of-type of selected element, `a` in this case, inside current parent and it will select all `a` elements because each one is first of that type inside its parent which is `li`. So you need to select first `li` and then `a` inside it. In this case you can also use `first-child` instead because only `li` can be direct children of `ul`.

```css
.selectedBuildingButtons a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}

.selectedBuildingButtons li:first-of-type a {
  background: #2d2d2d !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectedBuildingButtons">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector: `.selectedBuildingButtons li:first-of-type a`

If only want to target the first link in every li use `.selectedBuildingButtons li a:first-of-type` in below example.

Observe the difference between both.

```css
.selectedBuildingButtons a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}

.selectedBuildingButtons li:first-of-type a {
  background: #2d2d2d;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectedBuildingButtons">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>1</a><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a small hack with nth-child instead of using first-of-type.

**CSS:**

```
.selectedBuildingButtons a:nth-child(1)
{
   background: #2d2d2d !important;
}
```

This will apply background only for the first occurrence. Hope this helps :)